# How can I DRY up my service in Angular 2

Tags: service, angular, parameters, get, dry

I'm working on a Angular 2 service and I'm trying to DRY up my code. My service returns data from an RESTful API (GET request). For the moment i only send one param (auth_token) but how can i deal with a call to my service with extra params ?

Here my basic call to my service:

```
this._dashboardService.getData('users')
    .subscribe(usersData=> {
      if (usersData.ok) {
        this.users= usersData.json();
    });
```

Here is my service :

```
getData(data) {
  let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('auth_token', authToken);
  return this._http
    .get(this._url+data,{ search: params })
    .map(data=> {
      if (data.status===200) {
        return data;
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to make this code work :

```
this._dashboardService.getData('users',oneParameter)
.subscribe(usersData=> {
  if (usersData.ok) {
    this.users= usersData.json();
});
```

I'm not sure how to proceed to make this (is it even possible ?)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your new object param and assign to another object that contains the auth_token.

```
getData(data, anotherParams) {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

    var myObject = Object.assign({'auth_token':authToken}, anotherParams);
    for (var name in myObject) {
        params.set(name, myObject[name]);
    }

    return this._http
    .get(this._url+data,{ search: params })
    .map(data=> {
       if (data.status===200) {
          return data;
       }
    });
  }
```